# Content migration from one template to another in Sitecore

Tags: templates, sitecore, sitecore7

I want to transfer content of items that belong to one template into another template.

For example, I have 5 fields in first template:

- Tags
- Image
- Download link
- Title
- Date

and 5 fields in another template:

- Type
- Picture
- Download Text
- Title
- Date

Here first two fields are different in the both the templates and remaining 3 fields are same.

So I want to migrate content of items that belong to first template to the second template. Also, I would like to highlight second template is a newly created template and currently no item from that template is created. So ultimately I am modifying the template of 100 items.

I tried overriding change template method of sitecore `TemplateManager.ChangeTemplate(Item item, TemplateChangeList changes)` but it empties the fields rather I want to retain the field data.

If anyone has any idea about this, please help.

Comment: After this operation, would you still need your original template? Or would it be ok if it gets destroyed in the process?

Comment: Ideally original template should not be impacted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there wouldn't be much difficulty to migrate all contents by changing the template. But, the main issue is that there are a number of page items which have to be changed to another template.

If you do, you can use PowerShellExtension. It takes only 1 second.

You can get the script idea from [Sitecore Workflow Is Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263398/sitecore-workflow-is-not-working/29286256#29286256)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to inhertitance this fields, (using the "Base template" Field).

A other solution is to create your own change template command.
You can found here sample code: http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/nederlands/dialoge-box-in-een-command/ (it is a dutch article)

In code use: `item.ChangeTemplate(template);` and fill in the new field with the already stored values from the old template.